# Audio Player on site fragile if code is tampered with too much

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, facebook

I am using codes on my sites that I have never used before just for the layout and music player.

The page/audio player works perfect on desktop and android devices if I use this page: http://chancetrahan.com/1abcd.html

The player only works on desktop versions if I use the index file at http://chancetrahan.com

I have followed the site speed up suggestions on pagespeed insights and have gotten it to work on desktop, but I just realized it's not working right, and not showing up right if I view from android browsers.

I'm not sure if it's broken because I compressed the .js and .css files when I transferred them to my site or not, but that is what I am thinking might have happened.

I noticed that when I remove the FB ROOT from the code, it breaks the music player, I have no idea why the music player uses FB ROOT, but it does, I'm not sure what rollups are, but it also says that common.js is running twice.

I have stripped down the code to the bare bones trying to replicate this layout/template/theme with minimal code use, and a speedy response. You might not be able to see some of the code because I am using cloudflare, but I would be happy to use TeamViewer to go over this and kind of get some insight form someone who understands this code.

If you could help me figure this out I would be really appreciative for all the help I can get. Thank you for your help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to break javascript files when trying to lower your pagespeed scores. If you're using Cloudflare, test it on development mode and see if it works. Often times rocket loader will cause a problem.

I hope you have a backup of the javascript files before you minified them. If you tried to minify code that was already compressed, there's a very high chance that you broke it.

Further, pagespeed is not as big of a deal as you'd think when it comes to SEO. I put a lot of development hours into making a Wordpress theme from scratch that can get a 100/100 Pagespeed score. It helps, but not a crazy difference in terms of search engine rankings. It's more about just being nice for your users.

Another thing to mention, if you're concatenating your javascript files, first check if [your server supports HTTP/2](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test) as this will actually make your site much slower if it does. HTTP/2 is the new version of the SPDY protocol which requires HTTPS, and will quickly and efficiently deliver many resources at once without the need for concatenation.